# Moving data betwen tables with "this"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a game that i'm working on and in it theres a shop that has two divs: a "Buy" section and a "Checkout". The first allows you to select different items and then move them into the "Checkout" using a button for each row. My problem is that i'm unsure how to move each selected row across to the second div (checkout).

Eg:

```
<!-- Shop Buy -->
<div id="buy">
    <h3>Purchase</h3>
    <table id="buyTable">
        <th>Level Required</th><th>Item</th><th>Cost</th>
        <tr><td>Level 1</td><td><img src="img/shop/pickaxe_rusty.png" id="item1"></td><td>50 Gold</td><td class="moveToCheckout">&#8658;</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Level 10</td><td><img src="img/shop/pickaxe_iron.png" id="item2"></td><td>500 Gold</td><td class="moveToCheckout">&#8658;</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Level 25</td><td><img src="img/shop/pickaxe_steel.png" id="item3"></td><td>5000 Gold</td><td class="moveToCheckout">&#8658;</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

The `<td class="moveToCheckout">&#8658;</td>`or ⇒ is what the user will click on to move the items across.

```
<!-- Shop Checkout -->
<div id="checkout">
    <h3>Checkout</h3>
    <table>
        <th>Items</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Price</th>
        <tr><td><img src="" id=""></td><td><input type="text" value="1" id="quantity"><td>X Gold</td></td></tr>
    </table>
    <div id="checkoutBoxes">
        <span id="checkoutYes">&#10004;</span>
        <span id="checkoutNo">&#10008;</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Additional info: 
I have an array for each item with all the info for it (cost, level, img src), would it be possible to use this to create a new row in the checkout section and insert the details into it using a for loop?

Comment: I've tried giving an ID and Class to each of the buttons, and onclick checks ID, if id matches one of the items then it creates a new row in the checkout and inserts the data into it from the array.

This method sort of works but isn't very flexible as i have to do this for each item i'd want to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly understand what you want, but something like this should look close enough :

```js
function buy(elem) {
  $(elem).parents('tr').appendTo("#co-table");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Shop Buy -->
<div id="buy">
  <h3>Purchase</h3>
  <table id="buyTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Level Required</th>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Level 1</td>
      <td>
        <img src="img/shop/pickaxe_rusty.png" id="item1">
      </td>
      <td>50 Gold
        <button onclick="buy(this)">Buy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Level 10</td>
      <td>
        <img src="img/shop/pickaxe_iron.png" id="item2">
      </td>
      <td>500 Gold
        <button onclick="buy(this)">Buy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Level 25</td>
      <td>
        <img src="img/shop/pickaxe_steel.png" id="item3">
      </td>
      <td>5000 Gold
        <button onclick="buy(this)">Buy</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- Shop Checkout -->
<div id="checkout">
  <h3>Checkout</h3>
  <table id="co-table">
    <tr>
      <th>Items</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Price</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <img src="" id="">
      </td>
      <td>X Gold</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="1" id="quantity">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div id="checkoutBoxes">
    <span id="checkoutYes">&#10004;</span>
    <span id="checkoutNo">&#10008;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was a lot simpler than I had imagined. Thank you very much for the lesson!

Comment: @AdamSalma you're welcome and yes, sometime it's easier that expected ;)